# Как закрыть консоль из которой вызвал java приложение?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, jar, консоль

Привет народ! Сорри за тупой вопрос.
Как закрыть консоль из которой вызвал java приложение?

я создал такой .bat файл:

**java -jar Application.jar**

Запускаю его. Он запускает моё приложение. У меня вылазит мой JFrame. А консоль остается до тех пор пока я не закрою этот Jframe. Если закрываю консоль приложение тоже закрывается.

Код main такой

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  {

        frame = new SomeFrame();
        frame.enterHowUnregistred();
        frame.init();
        frame.setSize(884, 595);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: наверное, никак. Потому что, в терминале открыт сеанс в котором было запущено java приложение. Если досрочно завершить сеанс, то вместе с ним и прекращают свою работу все приложения запущенные в нем.

Comment: Надо запускать через команду start. Тогда консоль сама закрывается. C:\>start /?
Запуск указанной программы или команды в отдельном окне. `c:\>start java  -jar Application.jar`

Comment: @Sergey, будет здорово, если вы напишите это ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Порылся в инете и нашел это: смысл в том что консоль почти сразу закроется и оставит только ваше приложение:

```
start javaw -jar Application.jar
```

Притом выполнять надо именно через javaw

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [команду start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) перед

```
java -jar Application.jar.
```